# What is causing all these "declare -x …" lines when I open a terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line

When I open a terminal on my Fedora machine (or ssh into it), I get a bunch of lines like this before the prompt:

```
declare -x CVS_RSH="ssh"
declare -x DISPLAY="localhost:10.0"
declare -x G_BROKEN_FILENAMES="1"
declare -x HISTSIZE="1000"
…
```

What is causing this?  This may have occurred after I edited my `.bashrc`, but I believe all I changed was to add another directory path to "PATH=".

**Update** (responding to [heavyd](https://superuser.com/users/820/heavyd)'s answer): I grep'ed `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` and `/etc/bashrc` for "declare" and found nothing.

I looked at `/etc/bashrc` because `~/.bashrc` contains the following:

```
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

I don't see anything in the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` scripts except the above code, "PATH=…", "export …" and "alias …".

When I run my `.bashrc` script (using "`bash ~/.bashrc`") or `.bash_profile` script I see the list of "declares", but no error messages.  (I see nothing if I run `/etc/bashrc`.)

`~./bash_profile` is very simple:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
```

**Solved**: Thanks [andrew.n](https://superuser.com/users/3094/andrew-n), your suggestion helped me track it down.  It turns out all those "declare -x …" lines are output if one runs `export` (by itself), and I had accidentally inserted a CR in between "export" and "PATH=…" in my `.bashrc`.

Comment: look in /etc/profile.d/

Comment: What should I look for in /etc/profile.d/?   What are all those files?  (Perhaps I should create a new question about it.)

Comment: Thanks. In my case it was the CR between export and PATH too :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run

`env - HOME="$HOME" /bin/bash --login -xv 2>&1 | tee foo`

to startup bash in verbose mode. This will print every line of initialization file as it is read, and every line of initialization file as it is executed, copying the output to a file called `foo`. Then you can look in `foo` to see what’s causing `declare -x` to be called.

Answer (score 12):

Figured out that lots of `declare ...` statements is the result of having `export` being run somewhere without an argument.

I found an accidental newline in my `.bashrc`:

```
export
VARIABLE=value
```

Which should have been

```
export VARIABLE=value
```

Comment: Yes. This is the correct answer. If you type "export" by itself in your terminal, you'll see the same declare -x output displayed.

Comment: Yes, this applies to me! I accidentally put the content of export in the next new line. I put them in the same line and it works.

Comment: This is it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is likely that it is coming from your .bashrc because you edited it.  You may have introduced a syntax error in the script which could cause that to be output.

You can make sure that these lines exist in your .bashrc by typing:

```
grep declare ~/.bashrc
```

You should see at least those 4 lines printed out to the console.  You can also try running your .bashrc script from the prompt and seeing if any errors are output:

```
bash ~/.bashrc
```