# print out at the start of terminal session

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is causing all these “declare -x …” lines when I open a terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/11015/what-is-causing-all-these-declare-x-lines-when-i-open-a-terminal)

I forgot what changes I have made to my Ubuntu, but today every terminal session I open begins with print outs of some settings like

> declare -x COLORTERM="gnome-terminal"
>   declare -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus->IjombjJic8,guid=c3a6ac60543d102ca749c6ca4b04a936"
>   declare -x DESKTOP_SESSION="default"
>   declare -x DISPLAY=":0.0"
>   declare -x EDITOR="emacs"
>   declare -x GDMSESSION="default"
>   declare -x GDM_LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
>   ...

I wonder what could lead to the print out and I like to stop it. It didn't happen until today after I restarted my Ubuntu.